# Create unique identifier for different row-groups

Tags: r, data.table, sequences

I want to number certain combinations of row in a dataframe (which is ordered on ID and on Time)

```
tc <- textConnection('
id              time       end_yn   number
abc             10         0        1
abc             11         0        2
abc             12         1        3 
abc             13         0        1 
def             10         0        1
def             15         1        2
def             16         0        1
def             17         0        2
def             18         1        3
')

test <- read.table(tc, header=TRUE)
```

The goal is to create a new column ("`journey_nr`") that give a unique number to each row based on the journey it belongs to. Journeys are defined as a sequence of rows per `id` up until to `end_yn == 1`, also if `end_yn`never becomes 1, the journey should also be numbered (see the expected outcome example). It is only possible to have `end_yn == 0` journeys at the end of a collection of rows for an ID (as shown at row 4 for id 3). So either no `end_yn == 1` has occured for that ID or that happened before the `end_yn == 0`-journey (see `id == abc` in the example).

I know how to number using the `data.table` package, but I do not know which columns to combine in order to get the expected outcome. I've searched the `data.table`-tag on SO, but could not find a similar problem.

Expected outcome:

```
id              time       end_yn   number    journey_nr
abc             10         0        1         1
abc             11         0        2         1
abc             12         1        3         1
abc             13         0        1         2
def             10         0        1         3
def             15         1        2         3
def             16         0        1         4
def             17         0        2         4
def             18         1        3         4
```

Comment: There's a good idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537041/applying-cumsum-to-binary-vector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another base R answer:

```
test$journey <- cumsum(c(1,head(test$number,-1)) >= test$number)
```

Result:

```
> test
   id time end_yn number journey
1 abc   10      0      1       1
2 abc   11      0      2       1
3 abc   12      1      3       1
4 abc   13      0      1       2
5 def   10      0      1       3
6 def   15      1      2       3
7 def   16      0      1       4
8 def   17      0      2       4
9 def   18      1      3       4
```

Comment: Well-spotted! I didn't pay any attention to the `number` field.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
tc$journey <- cumsum(as.numeric(c(0, head(tc$end_yn, -1)) | c(0, diff(as.numeric(tc$id))))) + 1

tc
#    id time end_yn number journey
# 1 abc   10      0      1       1
# 2 abc   11      0      2       1
# 3 abc   12      1      3       1
# 4 abc   13      0      1       2
# 5 def   10      0      1       3
# 6 def   15      1      2       3
# 7 def   16      0      1       4
# 8 def   17      0      2       4
# 9 def   18      1      3       4
```